# Finding peaks of a sine numerical series with python

Tags: python, list, max, min

I have a python list with numerical series (floats), as a result of a sine function.

For example:

```
[0.3, 0.7, 0.9, 1.0, 1.1, 1.0, 0.8, 0.4, 0.1, -0.2, -0.7, -1.4, -2.1, -1.1, -0.2, 0.5, 0.9, 1.6, 2.3, 2.2, 1.4, ...]
```

I know the functions `min(list)` and `max(list)` but this will give me only one min and one max values - for the example above `min(list) = -2.1` and `max(list) = 2.3`  -but my list contains many positive and negative peaks.

Another easy example:
[image: Sinus function]

My list would then be:

```
[-1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 1.0, ...]
```

The result should then be the following two lists:

```
l_min = [-1.0, -1.0, -1.0, ...]
l_max = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, ...]
```

Is there a function I don't know about?

Answer (score 3):

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import find_peaks_cwt
cb = np.array([-0.010223, ... ])
indexes = find_peaks_cwt(cb, np.arange(1, 550))
```

or

[peakdetect](https://gist.github.com/sixtenbe/1178136#file-peakdetect-py-L141)

Found both solutions [here](https://blog.ytotech.com/2015/11/01/findpeaks-in-python/)

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using `itertools.groupby`. You'll need to zip consecutive values first. This is what I'm working with:

```
In [177]: x = [0.3, 0.7, 0.9, 1.0, 1.1, 1.0, 0.8, 0.4, 0.1, -0.2, -0.7, -1.4, -2.1, -1.1, -0.2, 0.5, 0.9, 1.6, 2.3, 2.2, 1.4]
```

You'll then zip your data so you're working with tuples of adjacent values. Group by key where the first value is lesser than or equal to the second value:

```
In [180]: for _, v in itertools.groupby(zip(x[:-1], x[1:]), lambda x: x[0] <= x[1]):
     ...:     print([x[0] for x in v])
     ...:     
     ...:     
[0.3, 0.7, 0.9, 1.0]
[1.1, 1.0, 0.8, 0.4, 0.1, -0.2, -0.7, -1.4]
[-2.1, -1.1, -0.2, 0.5, 0.9, 1.6]
[2.3, 2.2]
```

Note that the peak/trough of the current group always starts in the next group.